# How to save variables from powershell instance hosting clr 4.0 in powershell 2.0

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run clr 4 in powershell 2 and that more or less works.
Only the scriptblock runs clr 4 which gets destroyed, along with any variable, after command ends.
How can I use the variables from the scriptblock anywhere else in the code?

Here's the example:

```
function test{

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock
    )

    if ($PSVersionTable.CLRVersion.Major -eq 4) {
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
        return
    }


    $RunActivationConfigPath = $Env:TEMP | Join-Path -ChildPath CLR4Powershell
    New-Item -Path $RunActivationConfigPath -ItemType Container | Out-Null

@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
"@ | Set-Content -Path $RunActivationConfigPath\powershell.exe.activation_config -Encoding UTF8


    $EnvVarName = 'COMPLUS_ApplicationMigrationRuntimeActivationConfigPath';
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($EnvVarName, $RunActivationConfigPath);


    try { 
        & powershell.exe -command $ScriptBlock

    } 
    finally {
        $RunActivationConfigPath | Remove-Item -Recurse
    }  
}

test -scriptblock {

    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll")
    $zipcontent = [IO.Compression.Zipfile]::OpenRead('dmake.zip').entries

}

#Rest of the code here
#How can I use variables from the scriptblock here?
```

I know I could do something like:

```
$var = test -scriptblock {
     #Running in Clr 4
}
```

It becomes a pain if you have lot of content and variables. I was looking something more along the lines of variable scope but any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Have you considered just installing a newer version of PowerShell?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That's not the suggestion I was really looking for :) but yes.  I use different versions of Powershell in different machines but these are a group of scripts for unattended installation and Windows 7 comes with Powershell 2.0. I'm trying to make my life easier.  Besides I'd like know how to do things in more than one way. You never know when you're gonna need them.

Comment: Since you're using `Invoke-Command`, or spawning a new powershell process, it is unlikely you will find an easier way to transfer the information than just spitting it out to the pipeline. (Which is your final example)

Comment: @Mack `Windows 7 comes with Powershell 2.0` Windows 7 is now 3 versions behind (more if you count the various builds of Windows 10 since that's how it's updated now); you should be looking to move away from it.

Comment: @Eris It looks like there are not too many options apart from that.